# Clickable element in div with shadow: inset

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I would like to have clickable/focusable elements in a div, which has an inset shadow (the .calendar in this example): https://jsfiddle.net/axel50397/846ostv5/9/

```
<div class="calendar">
    <div class="card-deck p-2 w-100">
        <div class="card mx-2">
            <div class="card-header">
                2020-04-01
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block">09:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block">10:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block">11:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block">12:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block">13:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block">14:00</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block">15:00</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Based on my small CSS experience, it seems impossible because the .calendar must be above its content… If it's not possible in CSS, I'm open to suggestions if any.

Answer (score 0):

Remove below CSS, you added. Now it is clickable and focusable buttons.

```
.calendar .card {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqv4fkjy/

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the purpose of the z-index was to have the shadow above the cards. My issue is to have the buttons clickable with the shadow above

Comment: It's not. My problem is to have the shadow on top of the `.card` while having the buttons still clickable, if it's possible or if there is a workaround of some sort. Your answer would put the `.card` in its natural position which is above the shadow. It doesn't solve the problem